# Controlling 1.5A Stepper with Easy Driver

Tags: stepper-motor, stepper-driver

I have a 1.5Amp stepper motor (nema 17 size) and I want to control it with an [easy driver v4.4](https://www.sparkfun.com/products/12779). The maximum output per phase for this chip is 750 milliamps. My question is: can I use this board to power the motor by using the current limiting pot on it? I currently have this set to about half and the board is getting very hot, and burns to the touch.
Thanks

Comment: What is "easy driver v4.4"? If your board is getting hot enough to burn, you should probably look into heatsinks. Is the board aluminum-backed by any chance?

Comment: Added a link, and no it is not